# make ViewPager smaller

Tags: android, android-viewpager

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager android:id="@+id/groups_of_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="100"
        android:text="There are not place for me" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

In the code above ViewPager occupies all of the place. How to make it occupy as much space as much as a content requires. As layout's "wrap_content" property.

---

UPD:
ViewPager is filled with:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/group_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/group_active"
        /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to ViewPager have size as musch as TextView in code above. How to make it?

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use **android:layout_weight** you have to set the **android:layout_height** to **0dip** like in this example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager android:id="@+id/groups_of_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dip" 
        android:layout_weight="3"/>

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dip" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Must there be place for me" />

</LinearLayout>
```